# No award_count field on any badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The docs say the default filter includes award_count, and I've made a filter with it in. But no award_count is returned on any badge route.

The exception being when a badge item is returned in another object, like inside a user. But in 1.1 the award count was supplied on the /badges route

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed with the next deploy.